# jQuery selectable list with nested table not sized properly in jQuery tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm implementing a jQuery tab in my MVC3 application, but one of the tabs is not sized properly. That is, some of the content is inside the tab, but the following strange formatting on my part is only partially inside the tab:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Edit Schedule</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        ...
        <div id = "scheduleData">
            @Html.Partial("_partialView", ViewData["data"])
        </div>
    </div>

    ...
</div>
```

My partial view renders many tables, one with just a head, and the rest nested *inside* a jQuery selectable list:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<ol id="selectable>
    @foreach (var obj in Model)
    {
        <li class="ui-widget-content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>@obj.ID</td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    }
</ol>
```

I'm not sure whether the tab sizing problem is happening because of the partial view, or my very strange formatting, or both.

It is worth noting that only the first table is inside the tab, and any other tables are consistently not in the tab, no matter how large or small the partial view is.

This is obviously a sloppy solution, and I was wondering if there is a better way to render a table row inside a selectable list so the jQuery tab is sized correctly, such as having all the rows in the first table? (which won't work because you can't nest a selectable list inside a table, to my knowledge) I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility exists to make a table a selectable item, instead of each row, but due to formatting issues I adopted the following solution instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scheduleTable tr").click(function () {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if (href) {
            $("#editDialog").dialog({ modal: true });
        }
    });
});
```

The markup then has an edit link in each row, which the Javascript watches, then creates a jQuery dialog box.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        ...
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var obj in Model) 
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
                ...
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="editDialog" title="Edit Entry" style="display:none">
    ...
</div>
```